# Wiring for ceiling fan with light

Tags: fans

I have separate wall switches to control fan and light, both black, white, ground (no red).  What are my connections to the ceiling fan/light

Comment: What other wires are in the box? Can you post a picture?

Comment: The question is impossible to answer with the information available.

Comment: VTC unless further information can be provided. As it stands it is unclear what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to turn one switch on and the other off, and then, using a voltmeter, see which wire has power at the j-box.